# A question about how to represent $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ differently

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, roots-of-unity

I am reading Dummit & Foote for studying undergraduate level field theory, and here is what I see on Page 555:

[image]

I followed the words of writers and understood the proof for a statement

$$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_8) = \mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{2})$$

where $\zeta_8$ denotes the primitive 8th root of unity.

So here I am wondering whether we have a more generalized version of this statement for any arbitrary $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$, for example

$$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n) = \mathbb{Q}(i, ?)$$

where $\zeta_n$ denotes the primitive nth root of unity for some arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Can somebody tell me whether we really have this generalization? If so, which reference should I read to study it more deeply? Thanks!

Comment: You could use $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{mn})=\Bbb Q(\zeta_n,\zeta_m)$ in general for coprime $m,n$, so for example $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{12}) = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3, \zeta_4) = \mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{3})$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you for your suggestion! Is the identity in your reply true for any $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$? Or have some conditions for the choice of $m,n$?

Comment: Good question!  Try to read the comment again!

Comment: @DietrichBurde HAHAHA... Sorry, my bad! I didn't see "coprime"... Thanks! Also, I am wondering what will happen if $m,n$ have some common factor(s). Will one be contained in another?

Comment: @ZYX I believe @DietrichBurde’s idea was for you to take an extension by a single root of unity, and rewrite it as an extension by multiple roots of comprime degree. This reduces your problem into studying the extensions by roots of unity of degree a power of a prime, for example

Comment: @Gauss Thanks! I am studying this through trying more example like $\zeta_4, \zeta_6,\zeta_24$, and I am trying to prove it when $m,n$ are coprime.

Comment: This really depends on what you would consider a generalization of the statement. One version of the question might be, if it is alway possible to express $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ as $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n_1]{a_1},...\sqrt[n_k]{a_k})$ for $a_1,...,a_k\in \mathbb{Q}$. The answer to that is NO, only $n$ dividing $24$ have this property (and $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{24})=\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ for instance). (See if you can prove this using some Galois theory.)

Comment: @TimSeifert Thanks! I just now managed to prove $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{24}) = \mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$, and I am wondering what you mean by "only n
 dividing 24 have this property". Could you please explain more about it?

Comment: I meant that if $n$ is not $1,2,3,4,6,8,12$ or $24$, it is not possible to express $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ in the form I suggested. That is so say that you cannot find elements $a_1,...,a_k\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that adjoining all $\sqrt[n_i]{a_i}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ gives the same field as $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$. To bar interpretations like "$\sqrt[n]{1}$" as a counterexample, we should also demand that $X^{n_i}-a_i$ has no rational roots. ...

Comment: ... If you then consider the Galois group of such a representation, you should at first rule out any putative exponents $n_i\geq 3$ (since they would lead to a nonabelian Galois group). From there, the question just boils down to determining all $n$ for which the unit group $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^{\times}$ has exponent 2, which is the short list I gave at the start. See if you can fill in the arguments of this outline - if they give you trouble, I could also post an answer with expanded details. :)

Comment: @TimSeifert Your help is greatly appreciated bro! I will try it and see how it goes. If I still meet some trouble, I will tell you.